# I can't get my android app running on react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I can't run my project. There are 2 errors I'm trying to fix, but I get nothing.

I did everything that is written here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd BabyMobile

C:\Windows\System32\BabyMobile>react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  C:\Windows\System32\BabyMobile\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug: error: directory does not exist.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

C:\Windows\System32\BabyMobile>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Can you please help me?

**FIXED: updated android studio, project initialized in normal CMD(not as admin). The second problem was, that i turned on emulator after running react-natice run-android so you HAVE TO start emulator first !

Comment: Can you post the full logs?

Comment: run a command adb devices to check if there is any device connected to your system.

Comment: full log is there, cmd runned, but there isn't any device connected